# C# simple regex match doesnt work properly for me

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to write some code in C# to extract information out of a string using a regex:

```
var regex = new Regex("href=/skin/(.*)");
var matches = regex.Matches(line);
foreach (string regfr in matches)
    MessageBox.Show(regfr);
```

I'm doing something REALLY WRONG, I've done regex before but here it's much more confusing.

I want to turn:

```
<a href="/skin/result1">
```

into:

```
result1
```

i used this in php on preg_match which is easy to use..

```
a%20href="/skin/(.*)"
```

and it worked, this is probably really easy, but I'm extremely confused with the way these object-oriented things work :P

Comment: Where are double quotes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `var matches = regex.Matches(line);`, `matches` is a MatchCollection. You cannot declare the items as strings.

Your error message says that a `Match` object cannot be cast to a `String`.

You should first cast the MatchCollection to the array or list of something that can be iterated. Like this:

```
var regex = new Regex(@"href=""/skin/([^""]*)(?="")");
var line = @"<a href=""/skin/result1"">";
var matches = regex.Matches(line);
foreach (var regfr in matches.Cast<Match>().ToList())
    MessageBox.Show(regfr.Groups[1].Value);
```

Comment: it works,so thank you for that,im not sure what this means:matches.Cast<Match>().ToList()

Comment: @timo_pomer: BTW, using this `.Cast()` allows you to use LINQ on the match collection. It turned out a very handy thing for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
var regex = new Regex("href=\"/skin/(.+?)\"");
var matches = regex.Matches(line);
foreach (string regfr in matches)
    MessageBox.Show(regfr);
```

The only issue with your current Regex pattern is that it is missing `"` after `=`. So, `href=/skin/(.*)` must be `href="/skin/(.*)`

Comment: i see you escaped many things.2 questions.1:why .+? and not all matches like i did? 2:im getting this error http://i.imgur.com/bLpTt1p.png